# When two people work on separate features but have a common feature

Tags: git, git-workflow

Alice works on feature A (branch A) and Bob on feature B (branch B), and after some time after each work on their branch, they realize they both need a common functionality implemented, how should this situation be handled?

Should a branch (branch C) be created for this common feature? So that once the common feature is completed in branch C, Alice and Bob merge it to their branches?

Is it going to be a problem when branch A and branch B are merged into the master branch?

Another question\scenario: what happens if either Bob already implemented the common functionality in his branch? They realize afterwards that Alice needs it for her feature too. It wouldn't be feasible for Alice to implement it. It would I think also create problems when merging into master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard GIT workflow you have a develop branch (amongst other branches like release, hotfix, ...) and your developer/feature branches. If a developer B needs featureA from developer A then developer A would have to merge his/her branch into the develop branch so that developer B can then merge the develop branch into his/her own feature branch.

The common feature should only be implemented by one of the developers and then merged into every other developers branch.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: But with the standard workflow, I can't figure out some scenarios. In your example, what happens if developer A merge his branch into the develop branch when the feature he's working on is not completed yet? Developer B might finish his work on branch B sooner than developer A and the feature needs to be released.
In other words, developers can't merge their feature branches into the develop branch without having the features completed.

Comment: The develop branch would contain developer's A unfinished work, which obviously it's not what we want.

Comment: No developerA should only merge finished features into the develop branch. For a shared feature a seperate feature branch should be created and merged into develop

Comment: Just to be sure, isn't this what I am suggesting in the question too? Create a branch (C) for the common feature, implement the common functionality there, and merge into the feature branches. The only difference is you are saying to merge the common feature branch into the 'develop' branch, but since this is a partial implementation too, I don't think it should go into the 'develop' branch. Only complete features should be merged in to the develop branch.

Comment: Yeah I thought you were talking about a complete feature not just a partial implementation. Then I would merge branch C into the developers branches. You are correct the develop branch should only contain finished features

Comment: Thank you for confirming, so I know I got it right. I am trying to make sure I am not using a null pointer without realizing it :) That won't turn out well